# Align Divs Horizontally in IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I have a problem when trying to keep my divs aligned horizontally in IE7, they work fine in every other browser, is there a work around? [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KarinaMcG/tDfCR/13/)

```
<div id="christmas_promotion_boxes">
            <div id="christmas_promo_1">
                <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
            </div>
            <div id="christmas_promo_2">
            <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
            </div>
            <div id="christmas_promo_3">
                <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
            </div>
        </div>

#christmas_promotion_boxes {width:1000px; margin:0 auto 0 auto; text-align:center;}
#christmas_promotion_boxes div
{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float: left`

```
#christmas_promotion_boxes div
{
display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  padding-left: 4px
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/oNOYOXuy/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

**The Code Change:**

```
#christmas_promotion_boxes {
   width:100%;
   margin:0 auto 0 auto;
   text-align:center;
   display:table-cell;
   float:left;
}
#christmas_promotion_boxes div{
   display:inline;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tDfCR/15/)**

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` in older versions of IE only works for elements whose default display type is `inline`. Replace your divs with `span` and it should work in IE.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mxxdn/)

HTML

```
<div id="christmas_promotion_boxes">
        <span id="christmas_promo_1">
            <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
        </span>
        <span id="christmas_promo_2">
        <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
        </span>
        <span id="christmas_promo_3">
            <img src="http://lilliemcferrin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/vivid_flowers-wide.jpg" width="200" height="100">
        </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#christmas_promotion_boxes {width:1000px; margin:0 auto 0 auto; text-align:center;}
#christmas_promotion_boxes span
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this :

```
#christmas_promotion_boxes div
{
 display:inline;
}
```

This will work.